# How to change status bar color in android api level 19?

Tags: android

I have the following code. I can only see the action bar color change. But, the status bar does not change.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- App branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#009688</item>
        <!-- Darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00796B</item>
        <!-- Theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#536DFE</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: The status bar color will only apply to API21+ (Lollipop)

Comment: There is a library to do this but do not bother. You will be refactoring code and adding a dependency for 1 API level

Comment: yes it's totally worth it as it will look good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In API level 19, changing the status bar color is not natively supported. But the good thing is that Kitkat brought Translucent UI styling for both the status bar and navigation bar.

There is a very [nice library](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) which lets you tint the system bars with either colors or drawables you want.

[image]

**How to use**

**Step 1**
Add this to your build.grade in Android Studio.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
}
```

**Step 2**

Please set `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` or `android:windowTranslucentStatus` theme attributes to `true`or set the `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION` or `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` flags to your Activity window in code.

**Step 3**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);

    tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);

    tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);
}
```

There are lots of customizations that you can do with this library. Just go through the library page I gave a link to or check the [sample app](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint/tree/master/sample).

Comment: Nope, it does not work for API lower than 19. On the setup, it requires to set the status bar as translucent, which is not available before API 19. In fact, if you check the source code you will find the follow: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
   setTranslucentStatus(true);
  }

Answer (score -2):

Add this Code in you onCreate

```
    SystemBarTintManager tintManager;
    setTranslucentStatus(true);
    tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
    tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
    tintManager.setStatusBarTintResource(R.color.YOUR_COLOR);
```

And create a method somewhere in same class.

```
private void setTranslucentStatus(boolean on) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Window win = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        final int bits = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
        if (on) {
            winParams.flags |= bits;
        } else {
            winParams.flags &= ~bits;
        }
        win.setAttributes(winParams);

    }
```

SystemBarTintManager class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;

/**
 * Class to manage status and navigation bar tint effects when using KitKat 
 * translucent system UI modes.
 *
 */
public class SystemBarTintManager {

    static {
        // Android allows a system property to override the presence of the navigation bar.
        // Used by the emulator.
        // See https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java#L1076
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            try {
                Class c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("get", String.class);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                sNavBarOverride = (String) m.invoke(null, "qemu.hw.mainkeys");
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                sNavBarOverride = null;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * The default system bar tint color value.
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_TINT_COLOR = 0x99000000;

    private static String sNavBarOverride;

    private final SystemBarConfig mConfig;
    private boolean mStatusBarAvailable;
    private boolean mNavBarAvailable;
    private boolean mStatusBarTintEnabled;
    private boolean mNavBarTintEnabled;
    private View mStatusBarTintView;
    private View mNavBarTintView;

    /**
     * Constructor. Call this in the host activity onCreate method after its
     * content view has been set. You should always create new instances when
     * the host activity is recreated.
     *
     * @param activity The host activity.
     */
    @TargetApi(19)
    public SystemBarTintManager(Activity activity) {

        Window win = activity.getWindow();
        ViewGroup decorViewGroup = (ViewGroup) win.getDecorView();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // check theme attrs
            int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.windowTranslucentStatus,
                    android.R.attr.windowTranslucentNavigation};
            TypedArray a = activity.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
            try {
                mStatusBarAvailable = a.getBoolean(0, false);
                mNavBarAvailable = a.getBoolean(1, false);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }

            // check window flags
            WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
            int bits = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
            if ((winParams.flags & bits) != 0) {
                mStatusBarAvailable = true;
            }
            bits = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION;
            if ((winParams.flags & bits) != 0) {
                mNavBarAvailable = true;
            }
        }

        mConfig = new SystemBarConfig(activity, mStatusBarAvailable, mNavBarAvailable);
        // device might not have virtual navigation keys
        if (!mConfig.hasNavigtionBar()) {
            mNavBarAvailable = false;
        }

        if (mStatusBarAvailable) {
            setupStatusBarView(activity, decorViewGroup);
        }
        if (mNavBarAvailable) {
            setupNavBarView(activity, decorViewGroup);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Enable tinting of the system status bar.
     *
     * If the platform is running Jelly Bean or earlier, or translucent system
     * UI modes have not been enabled in either the theme or via window flags,
     * then this method does nothing.
     *
     * @param enabled True to enable tinting, false to disable it (default).
     */
    public void setStatusBarTintEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mStatusBarTintEnabled = enabled;
        if (mStatusBarAvailable) {
            mStatusBarTintView.setVisibility(enabled ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Enable tinting of the system navigation bar.
     *
     * If the platform does not have soft navigation keys, is running Jelly Bean
     * or earlier, or translucent system UI modes have not been enabled in either
     * the theme or via window flags, then this method does nothing.
     *
     * @param enabled True to enable tinting, false to disable it (default).
     */
    public void setNavigationBarTintEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mNavBarTintEnabled = enabled;
        if (mNavBarAvailable) {
            mNavBarTintView.setVisibility(enabled ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified color tint to all system UI bars.
     *
     * @param color The color of the background tint.
     */
    public void setTintColor(int color) {
        setStatusBarTintColor(color);
        setNavigationBarTintColor(color);
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified drawable or color resource to all system UI bars.
     *
     * @param res The identifier of the resource.
     */
    public void setTintResource(int res) {
        setStatusBarTintResource(res);
        setNavigationBarTintResource(res);
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified drawable to all system UI bars.
     *
     * @param drawable The drawable to use as the background, or null to remove it.
     */
    public void setTintDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        setStatusBarTintDrawable(drawable);
        setNavigationBarTintDrawable(drawable);
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified alpha to all system UI bars.
     *
     * @param alpha The alpha to use
     */
    public void setTintAlpha(float alpha) {
        setStatusBarAlpha(alpha);
        setNavigationBarAlpha(alpha);
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified color tint to the system status bar.
     *
     * @param color The color of the background tint.
     */
    public void setStatusBarTintColor(int color) {
        if (mStatusBarAvailable) {
            mStatusBarTintView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified drawable or color resource to the system status bar.
     *
     * @param res The identifier of the resource.
     */
    public void setStatusBarTintResource(int res) {
        if (mStatusBarAvailable) {
            mStatusBarTintView.setBackgroundResource(res);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified drawable to the system status bar.
     *
     * @param drawable The drawable to use as the background, or null to remove it.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setStatusBarTintDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if (mStatusBarAvailable) {
            mStatusBarTintView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified alpha to the system status bar.
     *
     * @param alpha The alpha to use
     */
    @TargetApi(11)
    public void setStatusBarAlpha(float alpha) {
        if (mStatusBarAvailable && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            mStatusBarTintView.setAlpha(alpha);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified color tint to the system navigation bar.
     *
     * @param color The color of the background tint.
     */
    public void setNavigationBarTintColor(int color) {
        if (mNavBarAvailable) {
            mNavBarTintView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified drawable or color resource to the system navigation bar.
     *
     * @param res The identifier of the resource.
     */
    public void setNavigationBarTintResource(int res) {
        if (mNavBarAvailable) {
            mNavBarTintView.setBackgroundResource(res);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified drawable to the system navigation bar.
     *
     * @param drawable The drawable to use as the background, or null to remove it.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setNavigationBarTintDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if (mNavBarAvailable) {
            mNavBarTintView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Apply the specified alpha to the system navigation bar.
     *
     * @param alpha The alpha to use
     */
    @TargetApi(11)
    public void setNavigationBarAlpha(float alpha) {
        if (mNavBarAvailable && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            mNavBarTintView.setAlpha(alpha);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the system bar configuration.
     *
     * @return The system bar configuration for the current device configuration.
     */
    public SystemBarConfig getConfig() {
        return mConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Is tinting enabled for the system status bar?
     *
     * @return True if enabled, False otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isStatusBarTintEnabled() {
        return mStatusBarTintEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Is tinting enabled for the system navigation bar?
     *
     * @return True if enabled, False otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isNavBarTintEnabled() {
        return mNavBarTintEnabled;
    }

    private void setupStatusBarView(Context context, ViewGroup decorViewGroup) {
        mStatusBarTintView = new View(context);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mConfig.getStatusBarHeight());
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        if (mNavBarAvailable && !mConfig.isNavigationAtBottom()) {
            params.rightMargin = mConfig.getNavigationBarWidth();
        }
        mStatusBarTintView.setLayoutParams(params);
        mStatusBarTintView.setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_TINT_COLOR);
        mStatusBarTintView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        decorViewGroup.addView(mStatusBarTintView);
    }

    private void setupNavBarView(Context context, ViewGroup decorViewGroup) {
        mNavBarTintView = new View(context);
        LayoutParams params;
        if (mConfig.isNavigationAtBottom()) {
            params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mConfig.getNavigationBarHeight());
            params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        } else {
            params = new LayoutParams(mConfig.getNavigationBarWidth(), LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        }
        mNavBarTintView.setLayoutParams(params);
        mNavBarTintView.setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_TINT_COLOR);
        mNavBarTintView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        decorViewGroup.addView(mNavBarTintView);
    }

    /**
     * Class which describes system bar sizing and other characteristics for the current
     * device configuration.
     *
     */
     public static class SystemBarConfig {

         private static final String STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT_RES_NAME = "status_bar_height";
         private static final String NAV_BAR_HEIGHT_RES_NAME = "navigation_bar_height";
         private static final String NAV_BAR_HEIGHT_LANDSCAPE_RES_NAME = "navigation_bar_height_landscape";
         private static final String NAV_BAR_WIDTH_RES_NAME = "navigation_bar_width";
         private static final String SHOW_NAV_BAR_RES_NAME = "config_showNavigationBar";

         private final boolean mTranslucentStatusBar;
         private final boolean mTranslucentNavBar;
         private final int mStatusBarHeight;
         private final int mActionBarHeight;
         private final boolean mHasNavigationBar;
         private final int mNavigationBarHeight;
         private final int mNavigationBarWidth;
         private final boolean mInPortrait;
         private final float mSmallestWidthDp;

         private SystemBarConfig(Activity activity, boolean translucentStatusBar, boolean traslucentNavBar) {
             Resources res = activity.getResources();
             mInPortrait = (res.getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
             mSmallestWidthDp = getSmallestWidthDp(activity);
             mStatusBarHeight = getInternalDimensionSize(res, STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT_RES_NAME);
             mActionBarHeight = getActionBarHeight(activity);
             mNavigationBarHeight = getNavigationBarHeight(activity);
             mNavigationBarWidth = getNavigationBarWidth(activity);
             mHasNavigationBar = (mNavigationBarHeight > 0);
             mTranslucentStatusBar = translucentStatusBar;
             mTranslucentNavBar = traslucentNavBar;
         }

         @TargetApi(14)
         private int getActionBarHeight(Context context) {
             int result = 0;
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                 TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
                 context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
                 result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(tv.resourceId);
             }
             return result;
         }

         @TargetApi(14)
         private int getNavigationBarHeight(Context context) {
             Resources res = context.getResources();
             int result = 0;
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                 if (hasNavBar(context)) {
                     String key;
                     if (mInPortrait) {
                         key = NAV_BAR_HEIGHT_RES_NAME;
                     } else {
                         key = NAV_BAR_HEIGHT_LANDSCAPE_RES_NAME;
                     }
                     return getInternalDimensionSize(res, key);
                 }
             }
             return result;
         }

         @TargetApi(14)
         private int getNavigationBarWidth(Context context) {
             Resources res = context.getResources();
             int result = 0;
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                 if (hasNavBar(context)) {
                     return getInternalDimensionSize(res, NAV_BAR_WIDTH_RES_NAME);
                 }
             }
             return result;
         }

         @TargetApi(14)
         private boolean hasNavBar(Context context) {
             Resources res = context.getResources();
             int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(SHOW_NAV_BAR_RES_NAME, "bool", "android");
             if (resourceId != 0) {
                 boolean hasNav = res.getBoolean(resourceId);
                 // check override flag (see static block)
                 if ("1".equals(sNavBarOverride)) {
                     hasNav = false;
                 } else if ("0".equals(sNavBarOverride)) {
                     hasNav = true;
                 }
                 return hasNav;
             } else { // fallback
                 return !ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
             }
         }

         private int getInternalDimensionSize(Resources res, String key) {
             int result = 0;
             int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(key, "dimen", "android");
             if (resourceId > 0) {
                 result = res.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
             }
             return result;
         }

         @SuppressLint("NewApi")
         private float getSmallestWidthDp(Activity activity) {
             DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
             if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                 activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
             } else {
                 // TODO this is not correct, but we don't really care pre-kitkat
                 activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
             }
             float widthDp = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.density;
             float heightDp = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.density;
             return Math.min(widthDp, heightDp);
         }

         /**
          * Should a navigation bar appear at the bottom of the screen in the current
          * device configuration? A navigation bar may appear on the right side of
          * the screen in certain configurations.
          *
          * @return True if navigation should appear at the bottom of the screen, False otherwise.
          */
         public boolean isNavigationAtBottom() {
             return (mSmallestWidthDp >= 600 || mInPortrait);
         }

         /**
          * Get the height of the system status bar.
          *
          * @return The height of the status bar (in pixels).
          */
         public int getStatusBarHeight() {
             return mStatusBarHeight;
         }

         /**
          * Get the height of the action bar.
          *
          * @return The height of the action bar (in pixels).
          */
         public int getActionBarHeight() {
             return mActionBarHeight;
         }

         /**
          * Does this device have a system navigation bar?
          *
          * @return True if this device uses soft key navigation, False otherwise.
          */
         public boolean hasNavigtionBar() {
             return mHasNavigationBar;
         }

         /**
          * Get the height of the system navigation bar.
          *
          * @return The height of the navigation bar (in pixels). If the device does not have
          * soft navigation keys, this will always return 0.
          */
         public int getNavigationBarHeight() {
             return mNavigationBarHeight;
         }

         /**
          * Get the width of the system navigation bar when it is placed vertically on the screen.
          *
          * @return The width of the navigation bar (in pixels). If the device does not have
          * soft navigation keys, this will always return 0.
          */
         public int getNavigationBarWidth() {
             return mNavigationBarWidth;
         }

         /**
          * Get the layout inset for any system UI that appears at the top of the screen.
          *
          * @param withActionBar True to include the height of the action bar, False otherwise.
          * @return The layout inset (in pixels).
          */
         public int getPixelInsetTop(boolean withActionBar) {
             return (mTranslucentStatusBar ? mStatusBarHeight : 0) + (withActionBar ? mActionBarHeight : 0);
         }

         /**
          * Get the layout inset for any system UI that appears at the bottom of the screen.
          *
          * @return The layout inset (in pixels).
          */
         public int getPixelInsetBottom() {
             if (mTranslucentNavBar && isNavigationAtBottom()) {
                 return mNavigationBarHeight;
             } else {
                 return 0;
             }
         }

         /**
          * Get the layout inset for any system UI that appears at the right of the screen.
          *
          * @return The layout inset (in pixels).
          */
         public int getPixelInsetRight() {
             if (mTranslucentNavBar && !isNavigationAtBottom()) {
                 return mNavigationBarWidth;
             } else {
                 return 0;
             }
         }

     }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't recognize SystemBarTintManager

Comment: is that your Activity class?

Comment: @androiddev You have to add the dependency to get the IDE to resolve.

Comment: You need to add this: dependencies {
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
}, from https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint